# Command raised an exception: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, discord.py, typeerror

Good evening,

I am building a discord.py bot, and have created a sample help command, but am running into a error. I use a dict to store a key-value pair called 'pogchampers'. If it's 'true', it prints out one help command, but if it's 'false', it prints out another. My problem lies that while the code works if 'pogchampers' == 'true', it does not work if it == 'false'. Here is my code:

```
@bot.command(name= 'plshelp', aliases=['helppls'])
async def helppls(ctx, self = None, guild = None):
    guild = ctx.message.guild.id
    print(data)
    for p in data[str(guild)]:
        if p['pogchampers'] == 'true':
            embedVar = discord.Embed(title="help", description=r"""
            I'm a basic bot, but heres some help if you really need it:

            some help stuff usually goes here

            """, color=0x00ff00)
            await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
            break
        elif p['pogchampers'] == 'false':
            embedVar = discord.Embed(title="help", description=r"""
            I'm a basic bot, but heres some help if you really need it:

            other help stuff usually goes here

            """, color=0x00ff00)
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

The error I get when 'pogchampers' == 'false' is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The statement that raises the error `await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)` is not included in your code.

Comment: please include the structure of your `data` variable in your command

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is with string indicies

Correct one should be:
`"astring"[1:5]`

Wrong one is this:
`"asring"['anotherstring']`

It seems to be the `p["pogchampers"]` part is wrong. P is a string you can't slice it with integers.

Comment: thanks. but what I would like to know is why does it work for if but not elif?